# Can't receive CTR-C after changing process group

Tags: c, signals

I have this code:

```
static void signal_handler(int signum);

int main(void)
{
    const struct sigaction sa = {
        .sa_handler = signal_handler,
    };

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    setpgid(0, 0);

    printf("[LEADER]: PID: %d, PARENT: %d, PROCESS GROUP: %d\n",
           getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp());

    for (;;) {
        printf("test\n");
        sleep(3);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    switch (signum) {
    case SIGINT:
        #define msg "INT received, exiting...\n"
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg));
        #undef msg
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

After changing the process group

```c
setpgid(0, 0);
```

I could not longer receive CTRL-C (SIGINT) from the terminal.
I'm using make utility to run this application.

If I run the process manually (without the 'make run' rule), signals arrive successfully.  I've red a lot on the web like:

> The SIGINT signal is generated by the terminal line discipline, and broadcast to all processes in the terminal's foreground process group.

According to this assertion, why if in the terminal, the foreground process is the application, it cannot receive CTRL-C interrupt? The process group is different between the make and application:

```
USER    PID  PPID  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND
vitto  1662  1661  1662      0    1 S    s000    0:00.16 -zsh
vitto  3956  1662  3956      0    1 S+   s000    0:00.01 make run
vitto  3969  3956  3969      0    1 S    s000    0:00.00 bin/application
```

but at the time that I press CTRL-C I'm looking the `bin/application`, and not the `make`. So it should send the signal to the `bin/application`'s process group. But apparently it doesn't.

So my question is what is the real receiver of the signal in this case?
Thank you in advice

Comment: The foreground process group is not "the Application" but the ... foreground process group. If you put your process in a **new** process group with `setpgid(0, 0)` (which would only happen if the process is not already a pg leader, as when your process is *not* started directly from the shell) it would no longer be in the foreground pg. The long and short of it is: don't mess which process groups unless you're implementing a shell.

Comment: And btw, don't call non-reentrant non-signal-safe functions like printf from a signal handler. No, that does not work "in general". Yes, all the examples you see doing that are wrong.

Comment: Oh I got it, at the time that make run the application he is the leader and he determinate the foreground process group, am I right? Then when I change the process group of the application it not longer belong to the foreground process group.

Comment: By the way, how can I know if a function is signal-safe? Is there a way to determinate it?

Comment: Yes, in the example you're giving `make` is the foreground pg. `ps` marks its state entry with a `+`

Comment: On Linux, there is `man signal-safety`

Comment: Thank you @UncleBilly, you were so useful!,